# ¿Cómo transferir datos 2 páginas de una TabPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xaml, xamarin.android

tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con Xamarin y me ha tocado hacer una tabbedpage y agregar 2 páginas (ContentPage) y todo ha estado bien, el problema es cuando voy a hacer un evento, es decir, tengo un ListView y cuando selecciono un item quiero que en la página 2 se actualice, lo más cercano que pude investigar fue usar ObservableCollection que lo utilicé para agregar datos a esa listview pero lo que quiero ahora es que el dato seleccionado me tiene que actualizar unos labels de la segunda página.

Voy a mostrar el código XAML de la primera página (aquella que tiene el Listview)

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ListItems">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="{Binding Icon}" Margin="5"></Image>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Author}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="11"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Como podemos ver, internamente a ese Listview yo le paso un Observable y lo demás excelente. Ahora voy a mostrar el código CS del evento del Listview:

```
ListItems.ItemsSource = listMusic.Musics();
ListItems.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{
     if(ListItems.SelectedItem != null)
     {
     }
};
```

Como podemos ver, el método **Musics** devuelve un ObservableCollection, ahora en el if es donde enviaría o en pocas palabras modificaría el valor actual de la segunda página y es ahí mi duda, ¿cómo puedo modificar esos datos? Voy a mostrar el código XAML de la segunda página:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="IMG"  Background="Red" HeightRequest="300" Margin="35, 100, 35, 0" Aspect="Fill"/>
            <Label x:Name="Titulo" Text="Título de la canción" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="Title"/>
            <Label x:Name="Artista" Text="Artita" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <Slider x:Name="Slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="1" Value="1" Margin="22, 0, 0, 0" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="35" MinimumTrackColor="#FFFE4164" MaximumTrackColor="White"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" CornerRadius="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions ="Center" Grid.Column="0" Margin="55,0,-55,0" BackgroundColor="White" ImageSource="tocarr"   />
                <ImageButton   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions ="Center" Grid.Column="1" Source="playy"/>
                <Button WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" CornerRadius="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions ="Center" Grid.Column="2" Margin="-55,0,55,0" />
            </Grid>
          
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Actualización:

He agregado esto a mi clase Music:

```
public class Music : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Author;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Android.Graphics.Bitmap _Img;
        private string _Name;
        private string _Path;

        public string Name { 
            get => _Name; 
            set {
                if(value != _Name)
                {
                    _Name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Author {
            get => _Author;
            set
            {
                if(value != _Author)
                {
                    _Author = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public Android.Graphics.Bitmap Icon { 
            get => _Img;
            set
            {
                if (value != _Img)
                {
                    _Img = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            } 
        }
        public string Path {
            get => _Path;
            set
            {
                if (value != _Path)
                {
                    _Path = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public Music(string Name, string Author, Android.Graphics.Bitmap Icon, string Path)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Author = Author;
            this.Icon = Icon;
            this.Path = Path;
        }

        public Music()
        {

        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Nombre de la Canción: " + Name + ".\nNombre del Autor: " 
                + Author + ".\nÍcono: " + Icon +".\nRuta: " + Path;
        }


    }
```

Y además agregué los binding en la segunda pestaña:

```
<Image x:Name="IMG" Source="{Binding Icon}" Background="Red" HeightRequest="300" Margin="35, 100, 35, 0" Aspect="Fill"/>
            <Label x:Name="Titulo" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="Title"/>
            <Label x:Name="Artista" Text="{Binding Author}" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0"/>
```

Mi método para enviar la información de pestaña 1 a pestaña 2:

```
 if(ListItems.SelectedItem != null)
                    {
                        var Music = ListItems.SelectedItem as Music;
                        MessagingCenter.Send("EnviarA", "Enviar", Music);
                        await DisplayAlert("info", Music.ToString(), "e");
                   
                    }
```

Y el constructor donde recibe la información:

```
public Music Music { get; set; }
        public MusicPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = Music;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Music>("EnviarA", "Enviar", (tema) =>
            {
                Music = tema;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como primer punto, no te devuelve un `ObservableCollection` ya que eso es un Tipo de lista, lo cual en su clase ya implementa `INotifyPropertyChanged`, lo que significa que si tu haces un cambio de un dato de esa lista, ese dato se ve automáticamente reflejado en tu `ListView`. Lo que el `Listview` te devuelve es un objeto que esta dentro de su `ObservableCollection`

Segundo para tu ejemplo, lo que necesitas usar es un evento o una objeto que la tengas global, si la cambias en un lado este se refleje en tu segunda pantalla.

Ahora pasando de los conceptos a la practica, deberia ser algo asi con la clase `MessagingCenter` Este ejemplo tenes que adaptarlo a tu problema real.

```
        public class Pestaña1
        {
            public void enviar()
            {
                Music music = new Music()
                {
                    Artista = "",
                    Titulo = ""
                };

                MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Enviar", Music);
            }
        }
        public class Pestaña2
        {

            public Pestaña2()
            {
                
                
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ListMusicPage, Music>(this,"Enviar", (tema) =>
                {
                    BindingContext = tema;
                });
            }
        }

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class Musica : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Artista;
        private string _Img;
        private string _Titulo;

        public string Artista
        {
            get => _Artista;
            set
            {
                if (value != _Artista)
                {
                    _Artista = value;
                    OnProperty();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Img
        {
            get => _Img;
            set
            {
                if (value != _Img)
                {
                    _Img = value;
                    OnProperty();
                }
            }
        }
        public string Titulo
        {
            get => _Titulo;
            set
            {
                if(value != _Titulo)
                {
                    _Titulo = value;
                    OnProperty();
                }
            }
        }

         private void OnProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Aca te agregue las propiedades Bindeadas. Observa el cambio en la Propiedad Text de cada componente.

```
 <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="IMG" Text="{Binding Img}" Background="Red" HeightRequest="300" Margin="35, 100, 35, 0" Aspect="Fill"/>
            <Label x:Name="Titulo" Text="{Binding Titulo}" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="Title"/>
            <Label x:Name="Artista" Text="{Binding Artista}" Margin="35, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <Slider x:Name="Slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="1" Value="1" Margin="22, 0, 0, 0" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="35" MinimumTrackColor="#FFFE4164" MaximumTrackColor="White"/>
```

Ahora tu opcion 2, con la propiedad Global. En clase App.cs declaras un objeto Musica;

```
 public Musica musica {get;set;}
```

Despues en tu pestaña 1,

```
 if(ListItems.SelectedItem != null)
     {
        App.Musica = ListItems.SelectedItem as Musica;
     }
```

Despues en tu pestaña 2: Dejas el ejemplo que te deje con el BindingContext, lo cual va a necesitar heredad `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Ahora en tu pestaña dos, le pasas al BindingContext tu propiedad global.

```
        public Pestaña2()
        {
            BindingContext = App.musica;
        }
```

Comment: Bueno, intenté la primera opción y no entiendo porque no funciona el método **enviar()** de la pestaña 1 la utilizo en el ItemSelected para enviar la información y aún así no funciona, revisé lo que me estaba enviando y todo está bien, además, revisé mi clase Music y todo está bien, el OnProperty(); me imagino que es el método de NotifyPropertyChanged ¿no? Es que soy nuevo usando esto.

Comment: He aplicado la segundo opción y sucede lo mismo, no muestra la actualización y me parece raro @Ramiro Barone.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, gracias!